What is the meaning of the temperature dependence of the Hall coefficient?
I would like to know the physical meaning of investigating the temperature dependence of the Hall coefficient.
It is known that the Hall coefficient is used to investigate charge carriers in a material, but what can we learn by investigating its temperature dependence? If it is to find out what the carriers are, wouldn't it be sufficient to measure it only at room temperature?
Also, what would it mean if the sign of the Hall coefficient changed above and below a certain temperature?

If you just want to identify the sign of the majority charge carrier then yes a single measurement would do. However the Hall coefficient depends on the density and mobility of the charge carriers as well as their sign and both of these can change with temperature.
For a material that conducts due to both electrons and holes the Hall coefficient is given by:
$$ R_H = \frac{n_h\mu_h^2 - n_e\mu_e^2}{e(n_h\mu_h + n_e\mu_e)^2} \tag{1} $$
where $n_h$ and $n_e$ are the hole and electron densities and $\mu_h$ and $\mu_e$ are the hole and electron mobilities. In a material with only one type of charge carrier this simplifies. For example if $n_h=0$ we get back the simpler expression:
$$ R_H = -\frac{1}{e n_e} \tag{2} $$
and here the temperature dependence of $R_H$ only tells us about the number density, which we could get from regular conductivity measurements. However when both types of carrier are present the temperature dependence becomes more complicated. For example you ask about the sign of $R_H$, and equation (1) tells us this depends on the sign of $n_h\mu_h^2 - n_e\mu_e^2$. If the densities and mobilities of the holes and electrons change differently with temperature it is possible for this to change sign.

Thanks for you answer. I understood the importance of the temperature dependence of the density and mobility. I have another question. If the sign of Rh changes, does it mean the material is semimetal? Such a phenomena can be seen in a simple semiconductor?

I don't know for certain, but I think $R_H$ can change sign only when both types of charge carriers are present. In metals the only charge carriers are electrons so $R_H$ cannot change sign. I'm not sure about semi-metals.

I see. It seems that I need to know a concrete case. Thanks for your sincere answer.
